# Cordova not firing OnResume function iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an app using cordova, which is just an webview from my website.
I just want to refresh my website when the user resume the app.
I followed the documentation from phonegap, which says I need to wrap my resume event in a SetTimeOut function: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br/?load-all=true", "_self", "location=no", "closebuttoncaption=Return", "EnableViewPortScale=no");
}
function onResume() {
    setTimeout(function() {
         onDeviceReady();
    }, 0);
}
```

I do know why, but it's working properly in Android, but iOS seems to do not regonize this "resume"

Any idea ?

Comment: if you use window.open with _self param you break cordova unless you have a cordova.js on your server, but cordova.js is different for iOS and android, so you should load a different cordova.js based on the user agent

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just changing "_self" to "_blank".
When we use "_self", the Javascript loose the context of window.